# why bundle can not send data to fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have following code which is sending a data to next fragment and it's working just only when send data to fargment that replaced, the problem is that I need to send second bundle data to another fragment

> working code

***this code work to send data to the fargment who will be replace when click on recyclerview***

```
    @Override
public void clickedItem(View view, Integer position, ArrayList<SoraDateList> items) {
    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), items.get(position).getName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment();
    SoraBackwardFragment soraBackwardFragment = new SoraBackwardFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("NameDetailes", items.get(position).getName());
    detailsFragment .setArguments(bundle);
    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)view.getContext();
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_Containers, detailsFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

***This It works to receive data in the Fragment replace***

```
String soraNameInIntant = requireArguments().getString("NameDetailes");
```

***When I want to send more than data to more than Fragment (BackwardFragment With DatailesFragment)***

> not working code only in BackwardFragment but Working in DetailesFragment

```
    @Override
public void clickedItem(View view, Integer position, ArrayList<SoraDateList> items) {
    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), items.get(position).getName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    DetailsFragment detailsFragment = new DetailsFragment ();
    BackwardFragment backwardFragment = new BackwardFragment();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    Bundle bundle2 = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString("NameDetailes", items.get(position).getName());
    bundle2.putString("NameBackward", items.get(position-1).getName());

    detailsFragment .setArguments(bundle);
    backwardFragment.setArguments(bundle2);

    AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity)view.getContext();
    activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_Containers, detailsFragment ).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

this code to recive data in BackwardFragment but not working not receive

```
String soraNameInIntant = requireArguments().getString("NameBackward");
```

i need to send data to BackwardFargment but i can not do taht
i need helpe to send data to backwardFargment

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set bundles to fragments that you are not targeting.

If you need some data later in backwardFragment, than you could probably save it in [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).

```java
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putString("NameBackward", items.get(position-1).getName());
    editor.apply()
```

And then you can get it like this:

```java
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String nameBackward = sharedPref.getString("NameBackward", "");
```